# Need Title of Sci-Fi Space movie - Girl escapes space prison-ship and lands on Earth

Tags: story-identification

I recall seeing the start of this movie during the early 1990s.

Action takes on a sort of space prison-ship. Prisoners have shaved heads, all dressed in light suits. The guards are wearing sorts of headsets - presumably to protect them from the psychic powers of the prisoners.

There is a bit of "romance" between two of the guards - (a guy and a girl). The guy takes off his headset, the girl insists he puts it back, he insist on having a kiss, she rejects him and goes about her business. He's upset by this and lingers around. The prisoners then use their psychic powers to make him a bit sick and weary - he slumbers around and opens doors of the prisoner cells. The prisoners crawl out. Other guards sound the alarm and shoot at the prisoners, but are overwhelmed.

Prisoners crawl to some sort of central gate and try to open it. The girl from the previous scene escapes the spaceship in a shuttle and lands on Earth - there she is rescued by a nerdy guy. Because she's unaware of Earth morality, she undresses in front of him before having a bath.

The movie had somehow decent visuals and effects, more style, more like Lucas THX 1138 - minimal but with style.

Comment: The start sounds like "[Escape from DS-3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yau0lSi8bgI)" - Warning NSFW (boobies).

Comment: Thanks for your input, but no, The movie had somehow better visuals and effects, more style, more like Lucas THX 1138 - minimal but with style.

Comment: Sounds a lot like "Something Is Out There".

Comment: Cheers, Thanks! It just might be that - I will check and get back with confirmation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title is "Something is Out There". Thou it is not a movie, but TV miniseries by NBC: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094551/. Thanks to user [Boelabaal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/42171/boelabaal) for the answer! Cheers!

[image]